# How can I empty a QListWidget without having it delete all of the QListItemWidgets it contains?

Tags: qt, qlistwidget

QListWidget has a member named clear(). The docs for this method state:

```
void QListWidget::clear () [slot]
Removes all items and selections in the view.
Warning: All items will be permanently deleted.
```

How can I avoid all of the items being permanently deleted? I just want to clear the lists contents so that I can re-populate it with different data (however, I want to keep the data that was in it to display again if the user chooses to do so).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[QListWidget::takeItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#takeItem)

```
while(listwidget->count()>0)
{
  listwidget->takeItem(0);//handle the item if you don't 
                          //have a pointer to it elsewhere
}
```

Comment: +1  Once you add a child to a parent in Qt, the parent owns the child and will delete it for you.  If you don't want the child deleted, takeItem() will "take" it back from the parent.  Make sure you store the pointer returned from takeItem(), because you're responsible for deleting it now (or re-adding it to the list later).